# Solr facet multivalued field performance issues

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I'm having some **huge performance** issues with facet queries.

I have an index of more then 20, 000, 000 of documents. And i'm doing for every query faceting search on 6 multivalued fields.

**I've set the facet.method to ENUM**... This increased the performance but still is unacceptable. Where the QTIME take's literraly over 6 seconds. My index is getting bigger every day... with approximatly 50k of document per week

Can someone help me! Is there any solution ? I've check everything, read all the tips but none was usefull so far

Did someone hit this problem ?

I'm using solr 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for [SolrCaching#filterCache](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#filterCache) and [Cache_hit_rate](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors#Cache_hit_rate)
Filter Queries uses Filter Cache and should be set accordingly for better performance of subsequent the filter queries.
Check the Cache statistics on the admin page for the hit ratio, if you see a low hit ratio means the cache is not being used. Fine tuning to a correct value would help improve the performance significantly.

Comment: Is there any explanation why in my index of 20 Million documents, with a query with filter queries where it returns me 13 documents in the result set... but when applying the my facets it takes over 6 seconds and if the facet is set to false. the Qtime is about 300s

Comment: Is your index optimized ?? Also check http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors#Cache_hit_rate

Comment: Yes the index is optimized. Perhaps i just noticed something... Since our application is always indexing.... multiple times per day as new items come in. The cache of the document/fieldCacheValue is always flush after each commit. Now my new question. Is there a way to say to solr config not to invalidate the cache of documents ?

Comment: Caches willl be invalidated after commits. You can autowarm your caches which would populate it so that the actual users get a better performance. Check Cache Auto warming Queries.